# Large Files in File Upload control taking very long time to send the request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I am implementing progress bar functionality to file upload control, I've noticed is that going into any event handler after browsing to a large file, takes a long time, even if the handler's code has nothing to do with the upload. I'm not really sure how the FileUpload control works, but it seems as if some copying is going on before it even gets to my handler.

Can anybody explain me what is happening there and how can i reduce the sending time of post request.

Comment: Can you please explain, what kind of event handler you are talking about ? And copying has nothing to do with uploading !!

Comment: its simple click event, it take long time to post the data, if file selected by fileuploader control is small like 20 kb it take 4-5 sec, and if i select larger file like 2 mb it takes about 1 minutes

Comment: then i guess its an internet speed issue. Its the same for me as well. I do face this issue while uploading 2 MB file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a FileUpload control for what you want to do. When a user POSTs a file, you have to think of it like a querystring parameter. It goes as one Http Request. If you want to do a progress bar you'll want to look into something that can interact with the server asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for help, why the way it works fine on VS web server and my local IIS, but i think i have to find new way to implement progress bar for file uploader :/

Comment: It's undoubtedly related to network speed or possibly computer speed if the server is slow.

Answer (score 0):

For large files you have to upload asynchronously. You can use the AJAX control tool kit to do that.

Go to this link and download the toolkit.
 [AJAX Control Tool Kit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/asyncfileupload/asyncfileupload.aspx)